How to add custom KEYBOARD COMMAND shorcuts to the PowerToys Run utility?
I would like to get Powertoys Run utility to display the Calendar Week and Day of the Year using cw or doy instead of using ) day of the year:



Yeah; I am pretty sure your going to be limited to what it already supports unless your willing to change the code yourself

This question is similar to: How to add custom shortcuts to the PowerToys Run utility?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @ReddyLutonadio, yes, I had looked at that question as well. The difference is that I am not looking for a keyboard shortcut to launch an Application. I want to add a shortcut to execute a command instead of using the default one. I am looking for either replacing or just adding a quick custom keyboard shortcut to "replace" ) day of the week with doy for example. Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I edited the question highlighting the KEYBOARD and command to make it clearer.

As far as I know you can not add custom commands from within the app or the general PowerToys settings. This leaves you with 2 options:

Writing a feature request (or searching & voting on a similar on) on the official GitHub repository.
Do it yourself: You can make a pull request,  fork the project or download the project's source code and customize it to your liking. But it will be quite the undertaking if you are not familiar with C#/C++, which are this project's main programming languages.

